# How to insert alt in LayerSlider?

Tags: wordpress

Please tell me if there is enough to put the alt attribute in these settings:
[image]

I am trying to add alternative text for images in the slider, but left displayed text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an alt tag to individual images on specific layers via Attributes. (it will be enough)